# Animating side-by-side figures in Beamer slide

Tags: beamer, diagrams, animations, slideshow

Supposing there are three images that represent the three steps of a process, it will then be desirable to have them appear sequentially, side-by-side, and also **in the same horizontal alignment**.

How can this be done in Beamer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To shown three images side by side inside of a `beamer` frame, use three `\includegraphics` commands in a row. Make sure, the combined width of all three images is smaller than the current textwidth  in order to ensure all images are shown side by side.
- To evenly space the images apart, add `\hfill` between adjacent `\includegraphics` commands.
- In order to sequentially show the images, make use of the `\pause` command.

Here is a compilable MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\pause
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
\pause
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works. However, what do you suggest as the correct approach for animating steps of a diagram? (i.e. drawing the diagram's steps with built-in facilities , such as the `picture' environment, and showing the elements one after another to the audience)